# How to read current immersive mode status via shell/ADB?

Tags: android, adb, android-settings, android-immersive, android-shell

Is there an Android shell command that can get the current status of Immersive Mode (i.e. `immersive.full`, `immersive.status`, `immersive.navigation`, or `immersive.off`)?

Immersive mode can be *set* via the shell command `settings put global policy_control immersive.full=*`, and other system statuses can be queried via shell (e.g. get current brightness level with `settings get system screen_brightness`). However, I can't figure out what command would return the current status of immersive mode. The goal is to programmatically detect if an app is currently in immersive mode (for use with automation apps like Tasker and Macrodroid).

I've tried various combinations of commands that sound likely, like: `settings get system immersivemode`, `settings get system immersive_mode`, `settings get global policy_control`, but most of these return syntax errors, as I don't really know what I'm looking for. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `settings put global policy_control immersive.full=*` all apps will enter in this policy due to you are using a wildcard *****

You have to indicate in which apps you want to apply the policy something like this `settings put global policy_control immersive.full=com.package.app`

Also if you want to apply the policy to all apps but no for some, something like this `settings put global policy_control immersive.full=apps,-com.android.settings,-com.package.app`

If you want to get the value from this you have to use verb **get** rather than **put**

For example, you can try `settings get global policy_control` and output will be the value you set using **put**, using last example, the output will be `immersive.full=apps,-com.android.settings,-com.package.app`

Hope this help you :)

PS. Check last command syntax, I'm using it without issue
[Command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RGUK.png)

PS2. This policy is not working on Android 11

Comment: Answer shared too late!.

Comment: I tried `settings get global policy_control` and it returned: 
`cmd: Failure calling service settings: Failed transaction (2147483646)`

Comment: (I'm on Android 12 fyi. Was your addendum implying that this command only works PRE-Android 11?)

Comment: @ETL That's right, I still trying to get this works, I found that could be an Android OS issue but I'm not really sure about it. Do you have System or Shell permissions?